# The same selector give diffrent results at regular browser and selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, jquery-selectors, behat

In Firefox in the console I can type:

```
$("a:contains('tekst')")
```

and I see

```
object { length: 1, ... }
```

When I do the same in `firefox` launched by `behat` with `sellenium` i obtain:

```
SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified
```

Is console in `firefox` under `sellenium` controle works different?

Comment: The `a:contains('tekst')` is not a CSS selector but a JQuery selector. It should works only when JQuery is loaded in the page.

Comment: If 'tekst' is part of an attribute try to use something like(example for href attribute):  $("a[href*='tekst']")   .If you have a text better use xpath //a[contains(text(), 'tekst')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What versions of Firefox and Selenium Server are you using? There are some combinations known to produce errors.

Comment: Firefox 47.0 and selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0

Comment: This combination is known to have some issues. I recommend using 2.53.1 along with Firefox 45.2 esr build. It might fix your problem.